# Cron job in a different timezone

Tags: cron, controlpanel

Is there a way of setting up a cronjob for a specific timezone?

My shared hosting is in USA (Virginia) and I am in UK. If I set a cron job to be executed at 1600 hrs every friday, then it will execute when its 1600 in Virginia.

I was wondering if I can setup my cronjob in such a way that it understands which timezone to pick. I am not too worried about daylight saving difference.

I have asked my shared hosting providers about it and they said I should be able to set the timezone in some cron ini files, but I could not find any.

Comment: probably better for http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think that you should check

```
/etc/default/cron
```

or just type

```
Crontab cronfile
```

and you should find

```
TZ=UTC
```

This should be changed (for example America/New_York). Second way is set in cron example

```
5 2 3 * * TZ="America/New_York" /do/command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks Bartosz.
1. There is no default folder in etc folder. And there is no cron folder either
2. When I set TZ="America/New_york" or "Europe/London" I get curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'TZ=America' error.

Comment: Note that the `TZ` specifications in the crontab doesn't affect when the job is executed. It just specifies which timezone should be used by the process once launched by cron.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `CRON_TZ` environment variable, excerpt from `man 5 crontab` on a CentOS 6 server:

> The `CRON_TZ` specifies the time zone specific for the cron table.
>   User type into the chosen table times in the time of the specified
>   time zone. The time into log is taken from local time zone, where is
>   the daemon running.

So if you add this at the top of your `cron` entry:

```
CRON_TZ=Europe/London
```

You should be good.

Comment: You should always use `man 5 crontab` and search for `TZ` first since usage of `CRON_TZ` varies a lot across different distros. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS does not support `CRON_TZ` neither.

Comment: Execute `crontab -e` and add `CRON_TZ=Europe/London` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to set different timezone for your particular cronjob, execute `crontab -e`via ssh and add

```
TZ=Europe/Moscow
```

before every cronjob.

[Full article here](http://blog.tural.us/setting-timezone-for-cronjobs/)

Comment: link is dead, some example would be nice ;-)

Comment: Archive.org snapshot of the dead link: https://web.archive.org/web/20160520231318/http://blog.tural.us/setting-timezone-for-cronjobs/

Answer (score 2):

To expand on AlexT's answer:

```
CRON_TZ="Europe/London"
```

is the answer.

p.s. If anyone is here looking for timezone fixes for GoDaddy, I recommend putting...

```
export TZ="Europe/London"
```

...in your .bashrc so that your console runs in your timezone.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 18.08

```sh
host@machine$crontab -e
```

then enter

```sh
TZ=Asia/Kolkata
```

**Note:-** Replace Asia/Kolkata with your desire timezone

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get it to work using CRON_TZ on Ubuntu 22.04. In the end I changed system timezone and restart cron.

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Kolkata
sudo systemctl restart cron
```

I spent a lot of time debugging before I figured out that I should restart cron after changing the timezone.