# Equality of PHP associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Quick question about PHP associative arrays.

Say there are two arrays:

```
$A = array("AAA" => "45", "FFF" => "108", "GGG" => "15");
```

and

```
$B = array("FFF" => "108", "GGG" => "15", "AAA" => "45");
```

Are these arrays equal? Does the position of an entry in associative arrays matter?

Comment: Depends how you compare them. If you take the order into account then no.

Comment: It's an easy test: https://3v4l.org/KbV2n

Comment: I did not know that var_dump can be used this way: `var_dump($A == $B);`

Comment: To people who are down-voting this. It isn't a terrible question. PHP is so inconsistent its probably something many people legitimately don't know.

Comment: @Cfreak this is clearly written in a manual. But instead of reading a manual people come here and post yet another question.

Comment: @u_mulder I do not understand why on this forum there are such restrictions. Yes, it is easy to me and many others to ask question instaead of searching information in the coumentation not beeng sure that the information is available. Than is advantage of forums. That is why the forums should exist for.

Comment: @u_mulder another day I asked for clarification on existing topic on this forum, and my question was disabled by moderator... That is the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289751/cron-job-in-a-different-timezone And that was my question: "@Bartosz Kowalczyk, could please clarify in you answer "TZ=UTC" is it what should bi inside of file named "cron" in /etc/default/ ?"  What is wrong with my question? This kind of forums shoul make our life easyer not opposit...

Comment: Please open http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see `This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.`

Answer (score 6):

According to PHP official document:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

## Equality:

`$a == $b`  TRUE if `$a` and `$b` have the same key/value pairs.

## Identity:

`$a === $b` TRUE if `$a` and `$b` have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.

## Demo:

```
$A=array ("AAA"=>"45", "FFF"=>"108", "GGG"=>"15");
$B=array ("FFF"=>"108", "GGG"=>"15", "AAA"=>"45");

var_dump($A==$B);
```

> bool(true)

```
var_dump($A===$B);
```

> bool(false)