# PHP - How to compare arrays are equal?

Tags: php, arrays, equals

[equal lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFW5e.jpg)

I search the records in a table and put them in an array. I search the records in another table and put them in another array. When the number of query rows in each table are the same, and the arrays are the same, the code is able to identify equality.

[different lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkDWa.jpg)

When the number of query rows in one table is different from the query in the other table, even though the arrays are the same, the code identifies it as different.

```
//Query1
while(){
 $vetor_xml[$cfop] += $vTotal;
}

//Query2
while(){
 $vetor_c190[$cfop] += $aux_vl_opr;
}


function identical_values( $arrayA , $arrayB ) {

    ///sort( $arrayA );
    ///sort( $arrayB );

    return ($arrayA == $arrayB);
}


$r = identical_values( $vetor_xml, $vetor_c190);
var_dump($r);

if(($vetor_xml=== $vetor_c190)==false){
 echo "ERROR";
}
else{
 echo "OK";
}
```

Here is link for download the code and slq data for test http://github.com/rafaelspfonseca/test

- Row NF 475 is not working
- Row NF 8989 is not working
- Row NF 9139 is working
- Row NF 9115 is not working

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [ask] and provide a [mcve] when asking a question

Comment: Try using array_diff(arr1, arr2)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equality of PHP assosiative arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37889319/equality-of-php-assosiative-arrays)

Comment: @fubar, i'm using == and ===

Comment: @peterchaula, I try, but not working.

Comment: @rafaelspfonseca - If you're using the equality checks correctly, you won't have a problem. Please post the code and data necessary to reproduce the error you're getting, and we can try to help. Without a reproducible example, we cannot help you.

Comment: @fubar, here is link for download the code and slq data https://github.com/rafaelspfonseca/test

Answer (score 0):

Try using `array_diff`

```
$array1 = array("a" => "sky", "star", "moon", "cloud", "moon");
$array2 = array("a" => "sky", "star", "moon", "cloud", "moon");

// Comparing the values
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
if(empty($result)){
    //array are equal
}else{
   //array are not equal
   //you can print the difference 
}
```

Comment: You have two array `$vetor_xml` and `$vetor_c190` . Use `array_diff`, If function return empty array then it is equal else not equal. This may probably help.

Comment: `array_diff` not workink
[link]https://www.imagemhost.com.br/image/xeJTJ

Comment: If `$array2` has everything in `$array1`, and also has extra elements, this will say they're equal.

Comment: key and value must be equal in both arrays

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved!** Follows solution.

```
function identical_values( $arrayA , $arrayB ) {

    ///sort( $arrayA );
    //sort( $arrayB );

    return ($arrayA == $arrayB);
}


$res = identical_values( $vetor_xml , $vetor_c190 );

$result = array_diff_assoc($vetor_xml, $vetor_c190);//add new verification
   
  
if(($tem_xml>0)&&(empty($res))) {

   //add new verification here
   if(empty($result)){
      echo"<p><b>EQUAL</b>";
   }
   else{
      echo "<p><b>NOT EQUAL</b>";
      $divergencia++;
   }
}

else{
    echo"<p><b>EQUAL</b>";
}
```