# Change time zone for a cron job on cpanel (crontab)

Tags: linux, cron, cpanel

I need to run a cron job with the following expression `*/20 16-23 * * *` by my time zone ( **Africa/Cairo** ) on my Cpanel shared hosting.

I created the cron job successfully but it has done by server time/zone ( USA I guess ). after a lot of searches, I found a solution ( didn't fix my problem ) that is put a `TZ="Africa/Cairo"` before my command so the whole line something like this.

```sh
*/20 16-23 * * * TZ="Africa/Cairo" curl example.com
```

And unfortunately, it didn't work for me! as after 12 am by my time/zone the cron job still working which shouldn't!!

> ( */20 16-23 * * * ) every 20 min between 4 pm and 12 am

Comment: Is it running as US or GMT? I've not seen that `TZ` before but couldn't you just do the offset from server time and your timezone?

Comment: I got it from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289751/cron-job-in-a-different-timezone, and I am not sure, what the server time zone is!

Comment: Run `date` from the shell.

Comment: Tue Jun 30 15:23:09 EDT 2020

Comment: Rather than changing timezone for whole server why not just check that how many hours ahead you are,  calculate the time difference and move cronjob that many hours so that it works accordingly.

Comment: I'm doing that already, you could say I was searching for the best solution for this if their code can do the tweak, And of course, changing the server time zone for me not an available option in fact. I was hooping there an option with crontab to do this.