# set specific timezone to for cron job cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have setup the cron job in cpanel to send push notifications to users. Currently this command is Running according to server timezone. But I want to run this cron job according to  "Las Vegas" timezone. So how I can set the timezone to specific cron job command to run on provided timezone time. Below is the command to send notification but I want to execute command according to Las Vegas timezone

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/xxxxxx/public_html/dashboard/artisan send_category:notifications
```

Comment: Set `date.timezone` in the ini file that PHP CLI uses on your system …?

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289751/cron-job-in-a-different-timezone and tell me if problem solved